# Upgraded Java Project missing JSF Framework in Netbeans 16

Tags: jsf, netbeans

I have recently upgraded a java maven project from JDK 8 to JDK 17 as well as changed IDEs from Netbeans 13 to Netbeans 16.

The project builds but when I go to run I get errors about the java server faces.
When I look at the project properties -> Frameworks -> JavaServer Faces the libaries are blank.

Is this an issue with Netbeans 16 or am I missing something?[image]

If I open the same project in Netbeans 13 it has JavaServer Faces library entries.

I have tried to update the JavaServer faces library's in maven, the JDK 17 and the tried to add a differnt version of JSF via maven into the project, but the proejct frameworks remain blank .

Comment: You can report issues here https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues